# Is there any method that can take "one" and return "1"?

Tags: objective-c, numbers

I've looked at `NSNumberFormatter`, but that hasn't worked, so is there a way of parsing written numbers and turning them in to actual numbers?

Comment: Are the numbers only zero through nine? Or are there numbers like twenty two?

Comment: If it's just zero through nine and not localised, why not just create an NSDictionary of strings -> numbers?

Comment: @JackStone since the number is bounded you could write a `switch statement` that does the conversion pretty easily.

Comment: Because I want you to be able to write something like "three one two" and have it return 312.  I'm pretty sure that dictionaries couldn't really accomplish that, unless I could parse the words, which I tried, but it wasn't parsing in order.

Comment: For instance, I tried parsing it, but when I would write "three one two", it would return 123, not 312 (I used `rangeOfString:`).

Comment: It would be better to use componentsSeparatedByString:@" " which would separate your "three one two" into an array containing the three words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter` will get you some of the way there, via [`NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-SW30). The basic formatting that `NSNumber` does will finish it off.

```
NSNumberFormatter * nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
NSString * numberWordString = @"three one two";
NSMutableString * digitString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
// Break up the input string at spaces and iterate over the result
for(NSString * s in [numberWordString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]){
    // Let the formatter turn each string into an NSNumber, then get
    // the stringValue from that, which will be a digit.
    [digitString appendString:[[nf numberFromString:s] stringValue]] ;
}        
NSLog(@"%@", digitString);    // prints "312"
```

Obviously, you'll have to put some work in to handle different input formats, lowercase, bad input (this will crash if `nf` fails to format -- it'll return `nil` which is an illegal argument to `appendString:`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work (for positive whole numbers anyway). This is just a starting point, you would have to check to see that the words were correct and maybe ignore capitalization to make it more robust:

```
 [self parseNumberWords:@"five two three"];


-(NSInteger)parseNumberWords:(NSString *)input {
NSArray *wordArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zero",@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",@"six",@"seven",@"eight",@"nine", nil];
NSArray *words = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSInteger num = 0;
NSInteger j =0;
for (NSInteger i = [words count]; i>0 ;i--) {
    num = num + [wordArray indexOfObject:[words objectAtIndex:i-1]] * pow(10, j);
    j = j+1;
}
NSLog(@"%ld",num);
return num;
```

}